# Image saving in different table

Tags: django, django-models

I have one view to upload the photos. I was using one model 'Photo' and model form PhotoForm. Image was saving in db successfully. But I added one more model PhotoTemp and associated modelfom PhotoTempForm and using them in the view instead of using Photo and PhotoForm. But while uploading the image it is saving into old Photo model instead of PhotoTemp.

I am not able to understand why it is happening. I am not using any kind of caching in my django project. Is django use any default caching?

Can someone tell me why it is happening?

This my new views.py file:

```
class ProgressBarUploadView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        time.sleep(1)  

        form = PhotoTempForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            photoTemp = form.save(commit=False)

            photoTemp.photo_type = 'product'

            if ProgressBarUploadView.cover_photo:
                photoTemp.cover_photo_flag='yes'
                ProgressBarUploadView.cover_photo = False
            else: 
                photoTemp.cover_photo_flag='no'  


            photoTemp.save()

            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photoTemp.file.name, 'url': photoTemp.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

This is my old view.py file:

```
class ProgressBarUploadView(View):

        def post(self, request):
            time.sleep(1)  

            form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

            if form.is_valid():
                photo = form.save(commit=False)

                photo.photo_type = 'product'

                if ProgressBarUploadView.cover_photo:
                    photo.cover_photo_flag='yes'
                    ProgressBarUploadView.cover_photo = False
                else: 
                    photo.cover_photo_flag='no'  


                photo.save()

                data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
            else:
                data = {'is_valid': False}
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

This is models.py file:

```
class Photo(models.Model):


    reference_id = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    photo_type = models.CharField(max_length = 70, db_index = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/',default='NoImage.jpg')

    cover_photo_flag = models.CharField(default=0,max_length = 5, db_index = True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-uploaded_at',)

class PhotoTemp(models.Model):


    reference_id = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    photo_type = models.CharField(max_length = 70, db_index = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/',default='NoImage.jpg')

    cover_photo_flag = models.CharField(default=0,max_length = 5, db_index = True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-uploaded_at',)
```

This is my form.py file:

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )


class PhotoTempForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `PhotoTempForm` you have used `Photo` as the model. So this is why the image is being saved in model `Photo` instead of `PhotoTemp`.

So change your `PhotoTempForm` as:

```
class PhotoTempForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoTemp <--change
        fields = ('file', )
```